# Load price phtml file in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have listed some products in my custom home page template.

I have tried to get price html in home page but its not working.

In magento 1.9 below code is used to load price template

```
 $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
      $productBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');
      echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product);
```

How to load this price template in magento 2

I tried below code

```
$blockObj= $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
                echo $blockObj->getProductPrice($_product);
```

But it returns 1 rupee as a price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get product price html using magento 2 below way,

You have to override `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` block and get your product object and call below function in your template file.

```
public function getPrice(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
    if (!$priceRender) {
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            'product.price.render.default',
            ['data' => ['price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices']]
        );
    }

    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'display_minimal_price'  => true,
                'use_link_for_as_low_as' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh i have updated my question please check it

Comment: Hello @RakeshJesadiya Can you please solve my question. It's same as like this answer. https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/246245/51810

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

```
protected $resultLayout;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout $resultLayout
) {
    $this->resultLayout = $resultLayout;
}

public function getProductPriceHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render $priceRender */
    $priceRender = $this->resultLayout->getLayout()->getBlock(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class);
    if (!$priceRender) {
        $priceRender = $this->resultLayout->getLayout()->createBlock(
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::class,
            ['data' => ['price_render_handle' => 'catalog_product_prices']]
        );
    }
    $price = '';
    if ($priceRender) {
        $price = $priceRender->render(
            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
            $product,
            [
                'display_minimal_price' => true,
                'use_link_for_as_low_as' => true,
                'zone' => \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST,
            ]
        );
    }

    return $price;
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***